# Javascript 'colon' for labeling anonymous functions?

Tags: javascript, function, anonymous-function, object-literal

What does this code refer too?

```js
queryString: function() {

//some code

}
```

I tested it in the WebConsole (Firefox) but it wouldn't execute, so I'm thinking that it isn't equivalent to `function queryString() {}`.

So what is it exactly?

Comment: should be: queryString =

Comment: its used to define functions within objects or classes, so i think you have takin it out of scope of the object.

Comment: you should check "Invoking a Function as a Method" part in https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_invocation.asp

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You are missing some code there, but I assume its part of an object declaration like this:

```
var obj = {
  queryString: function() {
    //some code
  }
};
obj.queryString();
```

It assigns a function as a property of an object literal.  It would be equivalent to this:

```
var obj = {};
obj.queryString = function() { ... };
obj.queryString();
```

In general, the object literal syntax looks like this:

```
{ key: value, otherKey: otherValue };
```

So the reason this didn't work in the console is that it was not enclosed in `{}` characters, denoting an object literal.  And this syntax is valid ONLY in an object literal.

Comment: It is not missing code. Please read labeled function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label#Labeled_function_declarations

Comment: @dy_ this answer was from 2012.  Feel free to update accordingly.

Answer (score 13):

This is probably inside a map/object declaration like so:

```
var obj = {
    queryString: function() {
        alert('here');
    },
    eggs: function() {
        alert('another function');
    }
};

obj.queryString();
```

Comment: So it's like a property of that object :) Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

The `:` is used when defining an object and its properties.

```
var obj = {
   queryString: function() {
      //some code
   }
}
```

Now `obj.queryString` is your function.

Comment: Is it queryString and object inside the variable obj? I thought queryString was the function's name.

Comment: @CarlosW.Mercado `queryString` is now a property inside the `obj` object.  `obj.queryString` is an object property, that happens to be a function.

Answer (score 10):

It's a label https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

```
var i, j;

loop1:
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {      //The first for statement is labeled "loop1"
   loop2:
   for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {   //The second for statement is labeled "loop2"
      if (i == 1 && j == 1) {
         continue loop1;
      }
      console.log("i = " + i + ", j = " + j);
   }
}

// Output is:
//   "i = 0, j = 0"
//   "i = 0, j = 1"
//   "i = 0, j = 2"
//   "i = 1, j = 0"
//   "i = 2, j = 0"
//   "i = 2, j = 1"
//   "i = 2, j = 2"
// Notice how it skips both "i = 1, j = 1" and "i = 1, j = 2"
```

Comment: Yeah, just wondered about a label before a switch statement, thank you!

Comment: No, the question's example of `queryString: function() { /* some code */ }` is not equivalent to your answer's example of a label before a switch statement. The question's example is part of an object literal declaration, which is totally different. In the question's example the symbol `queryString` followed by a colon ("`:`") is the name of the object member, its value is the function declaration following the colon.

Answer (score 1):

What the

```
queryString: function() {

//some code

}
```

means is the you can use queryString() to call the function that it refers to. This kind referencing is generally used if you want to define a class(or a pseudo class ;P) in your javascript. Something like this,

```
var application= { namespace: {} };

application.namespace.class_name = function(){

  function constructor(){
   return {
     exposed_property1 : property1,
     exposed_property2 : property2,  
     ...
     ...
    }
   }
  //Write property/functions that you want to expose.
  // Write rest of the function that you want private as function private(){}
};
```

So now at anyother part of the code you can create objects for class_name and use it to access the property1,property2 etc.,