# What does this JavaScript code in codiqa.ext.js do?

Tags: javascript, codiqa

I have never seen JavaScript written in this way (with a "randomword: function(){}").
What does ***this*** "randomword: function(){}" syntax actually do? Is this ECMA standards JS?

Excerpt of codiqa.ext.js below:

```
  init: function() {
    for(var type in this.types) {
      this.types[type].prototype.initType();
    }
  },

  refresh: function() {
    for(var x in this.instances) {
      this.instances[x].refresh && this.instances[x].refresh();
    }
  },

  callbackInit: function() {

  },
```

Comment: The value of an object's property could be anything, so it could be a function too.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize it was part of an array.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, the code snippet ***IS*** part of an object literal notation.

```
window.CodiqaControls = {
  define: function() {},
  register: function() {},
  init: function() {}
};
```

This is a duplicate question of [Javascript 'colon' for labeling anonymous functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384865/javascript-colon-for-labeling-annonymous-functions)

Question solved.