# what is Unexpected token function error in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi i was making a content slider but i got stuck at this error called Unexpected token function. the console shows that i have a error at this function
error: uncaught syntax error : Unexpected token function.

```
goNext function(){
    $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');
    if($('.oldActive').is(':last-child')){
        $('.slide').first().addClass('active');
    }else{
        $('.oldActive').next().addClass('active');
    }
    $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
    $('.slide').fadeOut(speed);
    $('.active').fadeIn(speed);
}
```

any ideas how to get this fixed...??

Comment: Missed `:` after `goNext`

Comment: Either that or it should be `function goNext()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of a JavaScript function is as so:

```
function name() {
code to be executed
}
```

In your code, you had the "name" and "function" swapped. The format of your function was like this:

```
name function() {
code to be executed
}
```

Try this instead:

```
function goNext(){
    $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');
    if($('.oldActive').is(':last-child')){
        $('.slide').first().addClass('active');
    }else{
        $('.oldActive').next().addClass('active');
    }
    $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
    $('.slide').fadeOut(speed);
    $('.active').fadeIn(speed);
}
```

Alternatively, if you would like the value of "goNext" to be a function, you could add a colon after goNext. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384865/javascript-colon-for-labeling-annonymous-functions) for more info on this. NOTE: This would only be valid in an object literal.

```
goNext: function(){
    $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');
    if($('.oldActive').is(':last-child')){
        $('.slide').first().addClass('active');
    }else{
        $('.oldActive').next().addClass('active');
    }
    $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
    $('.slide').fadeOut(speed);
    $('.active').fadeIn(speed);
}
```